# How to store Arabic language values from web-service in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to store some Arabic values I got from a web service, but when I select them from the database and show them in a `DataGridView` it just shows "?????". The three columns in the database are `nvarchar(50)`. How should I be storing them?

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Data.SqlClient; 

    namespace WindowsApplication1
    {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        string user = "gamal";
        string p1 = "GAM123";
        string p2 = "GAM123";
        string sdate = "05152014000000";
        string edate = "05182014235959";
        string node = "232641";
        string group = "Al Ahsa - ???????";
        string Compress = "";
        string m_d = "sa";
        string lang = "1";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

         test_ws.ppppWebServiceSoapClient ws = 
           new test_ws.ppppWebServiceSoapClient("pppp Report Web ServiceSoap");


            ds = ws.GetGroups(user, p1, p2);

            DataSet ds_ra = new DataSet();
      ds_ra = ws.RegionAlarm(user, p1, p2, sdate, edate, node, group, Compress, m_d, lang);
            ds_ra.WriteXml("region_alarm.xml");


            string connetionString = null;
            SqlConnection connection;
            SqlCommand command ;
            SqlDataAdapter adpter = new SqlDataAdapter();

            string sql = null;

            string ID = null;
            string nodegroup = null;
            string nodecount = null;

        connetionString = @"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; DataBase=hhhh; Integrated Security=True;";

            connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);


            int i = 0;
            connection.Open();



            for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                ID = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();                               
                nodegroup = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString();              
                nodecount = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString();
                sql = "insert into groups (id,nodegroup,nodecount) 
                values(" + ID + ",'" +  nodegroup + "'," + nodecount + ")";
                command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                adpter.InsertCommand = command;
                adpter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            sql = "select * from groups";
            command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            adpter.SelectCommand = command;
            adpter.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adpter.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            connection.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Done ..تم ");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After ensuring the NodeGroup column in your table is an `NVARCHAR()`, use parameters instead of concatenation, for both preventing SQL injection, and to make sure your data types are properly set. When you were concatenating the sql, the string literal was a `varchar`, unless you put an N in front of the literal.

```
   sql = "insert into groups (id,nodegroup,nodecount) 
            values(@ID,@NodeGroup, @NodeCount)";


   command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NodeGroup", nodegroup);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NodeCroup", nodecount);
   adpter.InsertCommand = command;
   adpter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Would this solve the problem with the Arabic characters?

Comment: Yes, when you were concatenating your sql together, the literal strings were implied varchar's.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
values(" + ID + ",'" +  nodegroup + "'," + nodecount + ")";
```

into

```
values(" + ID + ", N'" +  nodegroup + "'," + nodecount + ")";
```

However, you should really be using parameters instead of building an SQL string with the values in it.  That will get you around all of the escaping issues.

Answer (score 1):

When inserting in to database with inline sql you have to prefix the nvarchar value with 'N'.  For example: insert into mytable (col1) values (N'myvalue')